# Move IdentityModels to DataAccessLayer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to create my first 3 layers application with C# and MVC 5. I use Identity 2 for my authentication system and I installed it with this command :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.samples _pre
```

I found an article and question like that I need in website. I did step by step exact like this article. [Here is Article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1uPD.png)

I added a class library to my project and move my models in this class library but I got 3 errors on IdentityConfig.cs Startup.Auth.cs and Manage controller about

```
user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager));
```

Error detail is here:

> CS7036    There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'authenticationType' of 'ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager, string)'  PresentationLayer   D:\Projects\Divar\PresentationLayer\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 148 Active

When I ctrl+click on GenerateUserIdentityAsync I move to DataAccessLayer and this method.

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
```

In addition I changed my IdentityModels.cs name space to DataAccessLayer As well but I don't know why I have error Again,

Here Is my error image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1uPD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the authenticationType. There is no overload of user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync with 1 argument.

Should be more like

```
string a;
user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager, a);
```

Just a small tip as well... I've done this same task before and I got alot of value from looking at different ORMs integrated wit Identity. Maybe you won't but i think this is the one that originally helped me...

https://github.com/JudahGabriel/RavenDB.AspNet.Identity

Comment: I added a string.Empty, But I don't know is it OK?

Comment: you going to want to use CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType.XXXXXXXXX instead. According to the codes comments.